# how to retrieve single field data of type number from firebase in text widget flutter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to retrieve a field from firebase firestore document which is <String, dynamic>, please tell me whats wrong with the code.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('qazanamazcalc')
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
    return Text(
      snap.data.docs['countcalc'],
      // snapshot.data['countcalc'],
    );
  },
),
```

I am getting these two errors

> 'docs' method not found Receiver: null Arguments: []

and

> Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you using a stream, which is a continuous data stream that listens to changes in a collection or a specific document. If I understand your question correctly you just want to do one fetch on a specific document.

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('qazanamazcalc').doc('doc_id').get(),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {    
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var data = snapshot.data!.data();
      var value = data!['countcalc'];
      return Text(value);
    }

    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir! God bless you with what he loves for you.

Comment: I’m happy to help

Comment: I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71442782/how-to-change-values-dynamically-in-a-flutter-list-view-and-firebase-as-well) too, if you could help with this one too will be so kind!