# how to change values dynamically in a flutter list view and firebase as well

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview

I am incrementing the whole list because of the for loop on all the documents but can't solve how to increment/decrement the specific index, please tell me how to do that. I have the following code inside streame builder and list view builder.

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          final QuerySnapshot result =
              await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('mynamazstatus')
                  .get();
          final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
              result.docs;
          // ignore: avoid_print
          for (var data in documents) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('mynamazstatus')
                .doc(data.id)
                .update({
              praises['count']: FieldValue.increment(1)
            });
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_drop_up,
          size: 20,
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          final QuerySnapshot result =
              await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('mynamazstatus')
                  .get();
          final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
              result.docs;
          // ignore: avoid_print
          for (var data in documents) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('mynamazstatus')
                .doc(data.id)
                .update({
              praises['count']: FieldValue.increment(-1)
            });
          }
          },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
          size: 20,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

It works in the app UI as well as in firebase, but for all docs as per one tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could literally add a field called **index** to your document and use that as a reference to fetch the document that matches on that index. Let's say you're rendering the **InkWell** buttons inside a **ListView.builder** after fetching all documents from a **StreamBuilder** widget, as in:

```
StreamBuilder(
     stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('mynamazstatus').snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
        
       if (snapshot.hasData) {
         List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs;

         // return your documents in a list, for example
         return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               // ... use this index to both pull the document and to save to it as well

              DocumentSnapshot docRef = docs.where((d) => d.data()['index'] == index).first;

              // now, use the docRef to render your components, as well as
              // hook it up to the InkWell

            }
         )
       }

       return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
   }
)
```

Then when you build your widgets inside the **ListView.builder**, use the reference to the fetched **DocumentSnapshot** by **index** (**docRef**) and you can update it as such:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('mynamazstatus')
      .doc(docRef.id)
      .update({
        praises['count']: FieldValue.increment(-1)
      });                         
  },
    child: const Icon(
    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
    size: 20,
  ),
)
```

Comment: I am getting this error, Sir, by adding null check here `=> d.data()!['index'] == index).first;` does not working **The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')**

Comment: It's done sir thank you, now it says **StateError (Bad state: No element)**. This is because I have to create a field (named index) in each document right?